# What is a good way to select and take in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, select, iterator

Suppose you have a list of 1,000 items and want to select 10. The condition for select is expensive, but the chance of selecting is high (say 99%).

```
list.select do |item|
  item if is_ok?(item)
end.take(10)
```

This code is very inefficient because it checks each item, when it need rarely check more than 10.

What is a better, more efficient and Rubyish way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [lazy enumerators](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html):

```
list2 = list.lazy.select { |item| is_ok?(item) }.take(10) # .to_a to get an array
```

As per @tadman comment, let me emphasize that `.select { |x| x if p(x) }` is redundant, in a filter you use only the predicate: `select { |x| p(x) }`.

Comment: You fixed it but didn't remark that the `item if (...)` part is redundant and the clause itself is sufficient. This makes it a lot tidier. `select` doesn't care what you return so long as a logically true value means you want the item. Also lazy enumerators are great.

Comment: I suggest you keep your answer clean by moving the reference to @tadman's observation to a comment.

Comment: I deleted my comment. An attempt to take more items than the number for which `is_ok?(item) #=> true`  might signal an error condition, but one could of course check for that separately.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone here is fond of `lazy`, for good reason. The only downside is that  `lazy` methods have a reputation for being somewhat slow. If you only want the first 10 items that pass the test, that's not a problem, but if `n`, the number of items desired, is large, efficiency could be a consideration. In that case it may be better to simply return an array from a method when `n` items have passed the test ("short-circuit").

```
def select_so_many(arr, nbr_wanted)
  return [] if nbr_wanted.zero? 
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |item, a|
    next unless is_ok?(item)
    a << item
    return a if a.size == nbr_wanted
  end  
  nil
end

def is_ok?(n)
   n < 5
end

select_so_many([3,7,1,6,4], 2)
  #=> [3, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lazy` enumerator. It will stop the iterations once it reaches 10 items, so it will not iterate through every item in the array.

```
list.lazy.select do |item|
  item if item == 2
end.first(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [lazy enumerators](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html)

```
irb(main):001:0> arr = 1.upto(1000)
=> #<Enumerator: 1:upto(1000)>
irb(main):003:0> arr.lazy.select { |n| print "#{n} "; n.even? }.first(5)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

So you can see that even though `select` was called on an array with 1000 items, only the first 10 iterations were actually called  because that's all that was necessary to produce a result array of length 5.